# How to automatically attach VS to another process for debugging?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I'm debugging an ASP.NET application deployed on IIS 7.5 (VS 2010/Windows 7 x64) . After I make changes, I have to deploy it to the IIS folder and then do the following things (anyone of you should already know, I just list to demonstrate how boring and time-consuming they are):

- Click on the Debug menu, choose Attach to Process
- From the list, choose Show processes in all sessions
- Choose the right w3wp.exe process
- Click attach
- Click attach again

well, it's load of unnecessary works. Due to our system architect, this is the only way, we can debug straightforward by F5 button, but I wonder that if there's a workaround about this, so I can do all these things in on-click or short-cut key.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't set Use IIS in project properties on Web tab and set url to the required virtual folder name?

Comment: I did not know about it, can you give me more detail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/01/11/Attach-to-Process-with-one-shortcut.aspx

Create a macro in visual studio with the following:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Security.Principal

Public Module RecordingModule
    Sub AttachToAspNET()
        Try
            Dim dbg2 As EnvDTE80.Debugger2 = DTE.Debugger
            Dim trans As EnvDTE80.Transport = dbg2.Transports.Item("Default")
            Dim compName As String = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
            compName = compName.Substring(0, compName.IndexOf("\"))
            Dim proc2 As EnvDTE80.Process2 = dbg2.GetProcesses(trans, compName).Item("w3wp.exe")
            proc2.Attach2(dbgeng)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

change w3wp.exe to aspnet if thats what you want. Then go into the key shortcuts and just bind a shortcut to run that macro.

Comment: Also, that sample assumes that the user's username is from the local machine (it won't work with a domain account). I'd recommend changing `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` to [`Environment.MachineName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx)

Comment: I'm using VS2010, is there any change needed to this macro?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just go to project properties and select Use Local IIS Web Server.

[image]

If this is remote server you can do this too: [Using Visual Studio 2008 with IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-7/)
Although the article is about VS2008, the concept is the same in 2010.

Comment: @Vimvq1987 - trying to understand what was the problem. What exactly didn't work. Your IIS is local, right?